# How to select first n elements from an array with a min from each category

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of 100 products. Each product has a some attributes, category being one of them. Among the 100 products I want to select first n elements such that there are a minimum of m elements from each category.

To explain further, lets say I have 4 categories : a,b,c,d ; n=20 ; m=5. Lets say that among the first 20 products  6 have a, 5 have b, 6 have c and 3 have d as category. Since d has less than 5, I want to select 2 more products from remaining 80 products, so that I have 22 now but 5 from each category.

What I am trying to do is:

```
@productsProxy = @productsProxy1.first(30)

@taxons = @productsProxy.map(&:get_taxonomy).compact.uniq
@num = Hash.new
@taxons.each do |taxon|
    @num[taxon] = @productsProxy.select {|prod| prod.get_taxonomy == taxon}.count
end
```

Now for each key that has value less than m. I plan fetch more products. But I dunno how I can do that. A possible way is to use `select : @remaining.select{|p| p.get_taxonomy == taxon}` in the remaining array. But this will give me only all elements and not `m - num found`. Please can someone help me. Also this seems to be very inefficient. Is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: can you give one example array ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit  I want top 20 from the array. But if in the top 20 there are less than m products for a some categories. I want to fetch more products for that categories

Comment: Google bin packing algorithm. Might seem a bit over the top but you can do a lot with it.

Comment: @Tony, I don't think this is bin-packing, as nish wants to select elements in an array in order until a certain condition is met.  Bin packing would be something like finding the smallest subset of products that meets a condition.

Comment: nish, is the problem to determine `n`?  That is, given `m`, what is the smallest value of `n` such that there are at least `m` instances of each category among the first `n` elements of the array? If this is correct, the problem with your statement of the problem is that your first paragraph suggests that `n` is given, not to be determined. You may wish to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : No n is given, but if the condition is not met I'd like more elements that fulfil the criteria. Suppose n is 20 and only one category does not satisfy the condition. It has 3 items when minimum of 5 is required. Then I'd like to fetch 2 more items only from that category.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot follow the code given in your question, so will provide a general answer to the question as stated in the first paragraph, as per my comment on the question.  If my understanding is correct, you should have no difficulty adapting the following to your requirements.

We are given:

```
  categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  arr = ['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

For a given `m` (say, `m = 3`), we wish to find the smallest `n` such that each element of `categories` appears at least `m` times in `arr[0,n]`:

```
  def get_first_nbr(categories, arr, m)
    cat_count = Hash[categories.product([0])]
    n = 0
    arr.each do |e|
      n += 1
      cat_count[e] += 1
      return n if cat_count.values.min == m
    end
    nil
  end

get_first_nbr(categories, arr, 3) # => 10
get_first_nbr(categories, arr, 5) # => nil
```

- First create a hash that will keep a count of the numbers of times each element of `categories` appears in `arr`, as elements of the latter are enumerated: `Hash[categories.product([0])] => {"a"=>0, "b"=>0, "c"=>0}`.  There are of course many other ways to create this hash.
- When `n => 9`, `cat_count => {"a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>3}`, `cat_count.values.min => 2`, meaning we are not finished.
- When `n => 10` , `cat_count => {"a"=>3, "b"=>4, "c"=>3}`, `cat_count.values.min => 3`, so we are finished and therefore return `10`, indicating that the subarray of `arr` you want is `arr[0,10] => ["a", "c", "c", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a"]`.
- `get_first_nbr(categories, arr, 5)` returns `nil`, meaning that not all elements of `category` appear at least `5` times in `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have an ordered list and you want to take the top N elements from it, where N is a minimum number, or as many as are needed to have M representatives from each category in your taxonomy.  [`Enumerable#take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) has the semantics you want to express such am irregular predicate.  It returns elements from a collection while the evaluation of a block remains true.

Here's an example implementation. For clarity, I made a little class to accumulate the counts of members of your taxonomy, but one could just use a primitive Hash directly.

```
class TaxonAccumulator
  def initialize(taxons)
    @acc = Hash[ taxons.product([0]) ]
  end
  def add(taxon)
    @acc[taxon] += 1 if @acc.include? taxon
  end
  def full?(n)
    @acc.values.all? { |e| e >= n }
  end
end

def first_n_or_full_taxons(list, min_to_take, taxons, required_taxon_population)
  txacc = TaxonAccumulator.new(taxons)
  list.each_with_index.take_while do |e,i|
    e = yield(e) if block_given? # supply a block to extract taxon from element
    txacc.add(e)
    i < min_to_take || !txacc.full?(required_taxon_population)
  end.map(&:first)
end
```

Here it is in action based on your example categories:

```
categories = [:a,:b,:c,:d]
example20 = categories.zip([6,5,6,3]).flat_map { |cat,ct| [cat] * ct }.shuffle
example100 = example20 + (21..100).map { |_| categories.sample }
products = (1..100).zip(example100)
# => [[1, :a], [2, :a], [3, :c], [4, :b], [5, :b], [6, :b], [7, :d], [8, :a], [9, :c], [10, :c], [11, :a], [12, :c], [13, :d], [14, :a], [15, :a], [16, :b], [17, :c], [18, :d], [19, :c], [20, :b], [21, :a], [22, :d], [23, :c], [24, :a], [25, :c], [26, :b], [27, :b], [28, :a], [29, :c], [30, :b], [31, :a], [32, :b], [33, :d], [34, :a], [35, :b], [36, :c], [37, :c], [38, :d], [39, :c], [40, :d], [41, :b], [42, :b], [43, :b], [44, :b], [45, :c], [46, :b], [47, :b], [48, :b], [49, :d], [50, :a], [51, :d], [52, :c], [53, :b], [54, :b], [55, :d], [56, :a], [57, :a], [58, :a], [59, :b], [60, :c], [61, :a], [62, :b], [63, :c], [64, :d], [65, :b], [66, :b], [67, :d], [68, :a], [69, :a], [70, :d], [71, :b], [72, :a], [73, :b], [74, :c], [75, :a], [76, :a], [77, :a], [78, :b], [79, :b], [80, :c], [81, :a], [82, :b], [83, :d], [84, :c], [85, :d], [86, :a], [87, :a], [88, :b], [89, :d], [90, :a], [91, :b], [92, :a], [93, :d], [94, :c], [95, :c], [96, :b], [97, :a], [98, :b], [99, :c], [100, :b]]

top = first_n_or_full_taxons(products, 20, categories, 5, &:last)

# => [[1, :a], [2, :a], [3, :c], [4, :b], [5, :b], [6, :b], [7, :d], [8, :a], [9, :c], [10, :c], [11, :a], [12, :c], [13, :d], [14, :a], [15, :a], [16, :b], [17, :c], [18, :d], [19, :c], [20, :b], [21, :a], [22, :d], [23, :c], [24, :a], [25, :c], [26, :b], [27, :b], [28, :a], [29, :c], [30, :b], [31, :a], [32, :b]]

# with only 1 of each required, it stops after the first 20
top = first_n_or_full_taxons(products, 20, categories, 1, &:last)

# => [[1, :a], [2, :a], [3, :c], [4, :b], [5, :b], [6, :b], [7, :d], [8, :a], [9, :c], [10, :c], [11, :a], [12, :c], [13, :d], [14, :a], [15, :a], [16, :b], [17, :c], [18, :d], [19, :c], [20, :b]]
```